# How do I update the resource limits/requests for a pod without restarting the pod?

Tags: kubernetes

How do I update the resource limits/requests for a pod without restarting the pod? Is this even possible?

I am trying to speed up updating configs for my pods. But they are restarted each time (in a StatefulSet).

It would be nice to change minor configs like resource limits/requests without restarting the pod.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't update resources spec without recreating pod. Here is [related issue on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24913)

Comment: You'll soon be able to update pod resources in-place, see
https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1287